# Excepción de coma flotante ('core' generado) en una división en esamblador

Tags: ensamblador, x86

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
push rbp
mov  rbp, rsp

push rax
push rcx
push rdx
push rsi
push rdi

mov rax, QWORD[indiceVector]
mov rcx, 10
div rcx
mov rsi, rax
mov rdi, rdx
```

... y en la instrucción "div rcx" me dice "Excepción en coma flotante ('core' generado)" y no es una división por 0, ya que debugando me da 23 entre 10. Lo curioso es que en alguna otra función tengo un código casi idéntico y no me da la excepción. ¿Alguien sabe porque da este error?. Tengo otra pregunta: ¿Para dividir entre 10 la manera en que lo he hecho es la correcta o hay otra mejor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mirando [NASM Assembly Quick Reference](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2007/fall/cs301/support/x86_64/index.html) veo algo interesante con respecto a `div`:

> Divide rax by src, and put the ratio into rax, and the remainder into
>   rdx. **Bizarrely, on input rdx must be zero, or you get a SIGFPE.**

Es decir, deberías inicializar en 0 el registro que recibe el resto de la división, `mov rdx, 0` para evitar el error.